# Rails 4.2 Dry up Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, architecture

I have a User model which gets accessed through a REST API and ActiveAdmin. Since there is a lot  duplicated code (almost all) it might be a good idea to dry things up. There are a lot of topics out there handling this issue but i  do not find a *proper* way. I put some of the ideas i have below

### UserController instance in each controller

Again duplicated code gets created and the functions

```
 #AA
 controller do 
  def create
   @userController = UserController.new
   @userController.create(params)
  end 
 end 


 #REST API
 #Create instance through callback
  def create
   @userController.create(params)
  end
```

### Inheritance

I would like to have one basic CRUD controller lying above my model through inheritance like this

```
Class BaseUserController < ApplicationController
Class Api::UserController < BaseUserController
```

but (yet) i dont know how to do this in AA also in mind with the inherited_resource gem in mind

### Concerns

Also concerns seem to be a nice way. But i would then create seperate concerns for each action to have one concern to exactly handle one behaviour 
aspect and also to make them  more reuseable . This then again seems to unnecessarily bloat the app and also concerns are not really made to be used like that. (?)

### Modules/Mixins

Since modules cannot be instantiated but implement actions fully, this might just be what i am looking for. So each controller includes the desired actions or extend fro ma model rather than a class then.

The thing is - the more i read the more i get confused. I hope some of you guys might help me bring some light or i might turn to the dark side an use C# and .NEt again :D 
Thanks in advance!

### Example Code

I took this create method for a SMS resource in both, the REST API and the AA, where i call a couple of Services, but if complexity grows i have to add these lines in two places. How could i avoid that? Cant i have a basic SMSController which is used from the API endpoints as well as the AA interface?

```
 controller do 
  def create
       @customer =Customer.find_by_phone(params[:sms_message][:phone])
 SmsService.sendSMS(@customer[:phone],Cryptoalgorithm.sms(@customer[:id],  @customer[:recharge_token],params[:sms_message][:text].to_i)
       @sms = SmsMessage.create(:customer_id => @customer[:id], :text => params[:sms_message][:text], :phone =>     params[:sms_message][:phone])
       @customer.increment!(:recharge_token)
       redirect_to admin_sms_message_path(@sms[:id])
       end
   end
```

Comment: Maybe you should start by looking at questions: "why the fak is user authentication in the 'contollers', if it's clearly a domain business logic part". Here is a thing that will help you: stop trying to fit Rails in MVC architectural pattern. It's not related to it.

Comment: Interesting question. Your example doesn't make it exactly clear what code is duplicated, considering it's only one line. Is there an example you can give us where you have a good block of duplicated code?

Comment: Hey @JonathanAllard i included an example block. Hope this makes it clearer

Comment: Sounds like you need to do your actions as much in the model as you can, and try to make your controller action into a two-liner. (Tip: write the code you wish you had in your controller, then go implement it in your models)